# Fire TabControl Event after new tab is displayed

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I want to fire an event when a new tab is selected, after the new tab is displayed.

I have tried to use the `.Selecting` event which fires before the new tab is selected, and the `.Selected` event which fires after the new tab is selected but before it is displayed. I have also tried `.VisibleChanged` on a control within the new tab. Finally I tried `.Enter` on the tab itself. Both of these give a similar result to `.selected` the event is fired before the new tab is displayed.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fire the event after the new tab is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yea, that awkward moment when something you are sure you tried fixes the issue...

Comment: Mistakes happen! I make them all the time. Don't be ashamed :)